# Wine tasting experiment- Probability

Tags: probability

In a blind wine-tasting experiment, a panel of five judges is to be served
one of two wines, a French and a German. The wine is to be selected by
tossing a fair coin.

Assume each judge has probability $3/4$ of guessing
correctly independently of the other judges. If $4$ out of $5$ judges guess
a wine to be French, what is the probability that it was actually the
German wine that was served?

My try:

As four them guessed it incorrect(i.e French), their probability of getting a German and guessing incorrectly should be $4*(1/2)*(1/4)$.

While the last person guessed it correctly, therefore his probability should be $(1/2)*(3/4)$

Therefore final answer should be multiplication of these two.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using conditional probabilities:
$$
P(\text{German correct}\mid 4\text{ guessed French})=\frac{P(\text{German}, 4\text{ guessed French})}{P(4\text{ guessed French})}
$$
The probability that the wine is German, and also 4 judges guessed French, is given by the binomial
$$
\frac12 {5 \choose 4}\left(\frac14\right)^4\left(\frac34\right)=\frac52\frac34\left(\frac14\right)^4.
$$
Then, the probability that 4 judges guessed French, can be split
$$
P(4\text{ guessed French})=\frac12P(4 \text{ guessed French}\mid \text{French correct})+\frac12P(4 \text{ guessed French}\mid \text{German correct}),
$$
which can be calculated similarly with the binomial distribution.

Comment: I am confused about P(4 guessed French)? Can you explain?

Comment: @max The wine is equally likely to actually be French or German, so the $1/2$s are $P(\text{French Correct})$ and $P(\text{German correct})$ respectively. The equation is then the total probability formula. The overall formula being used here is Bayes' rule.

Comment: Would the final answer be 3/168? Just want to confirm

Comment: I get 1/28 as an answer. The numerator becomes 15/2048, and the denominator 105/512.